# How to pull from AWS ECR docker image anonymously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I understand we need to login to ECR to pull docker image from AWS ECR. How can I make it anonymous? Since we separate code, data and infrastructure (all open source) separate we do not find a need for the infrastructure part to be private.

I was able to find the way to create permission with *, not sure how can I make it anonymous so that anyone who wants to download does not need an IAM user access.

Below is the policy,

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublic",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure how can I create an anonymous IAM user as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/)

> Q: Can Amazon ECR host public container images?
>
> Amazon ECR currently supports private images. However, using IAM resource-based permissions, you can configure policies for each repository to allow access to IAM users, roles, or other AWS accounts.

The only workaround I can think of is probably putting a EC2 machine and the using NGINX to `proxy_pass` to the ECR url and using the EC2 IP for docker repo

Answer (score 0):

Starting 1 Dec 2020, You can use ECR public to pull container images anonymously.

Links to [How To](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/getting-started-cli.html) & [Launch Announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/announcing-amazon-ecr-public-and-amazon-ecr-public-gallery/)

> Anyone who pulls images anonymously gets 500 GB of free data bandwidth
> each month after which they can sign up for or sign in to an AWS
> account. Simply authenticating with an AWS account increases free data
> bandwidth to 5 TB each month when pulling images from the internet.
> And finally, workloads running in AWS will get unlimited data
> bandwidth from any region when pulling from ECR Public.